# Использование тайлов Google Maps в leaflet js

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps, leafletjs

Мне нужно отображать геопозицию агента на карте в своей CRM системе.
Могу ли я использовать Google Maps тайлы в leaflet JS в коммерческом продукте?
Я подключаю тайлы [таким](http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x=1324&y=3144&z=13) образом:

```
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
      maxZoom: 20,
      subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
  }).addTo(map);
```

Но я не знаю, можно ли так отображать карты в коммерческом продукте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот лицензия Google. Почитайте.
https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/ 
https://www.google.com/intl/ru/help/terms_maps/

Comment: Разрешено: Просматривать карты и добавлять к ним заметки;

Создавать KML-файлы и слои карт;

Публиковать Контент с указанием правообладателя в Интернете, в видеопродукции и в печатных документах;

Выполнять другие действия, разрешенные пользователям сервисов "Google Карты", "Google Планета Земля" и "Просмотр улиц". Значить можно добавлять заметки, спасибо)